# How to inject a secret key at runtime via AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using Spring boot and we have the following value currently existing in the properties file.

```
secret.key=123456 # lets assume 12345 is a secret key
```

We are using AWS beanstalk and wanted to stop adding secret data in code/git and instead inject it at runtime as an environment variable at aws as follows.

[image]

But how to achieve this in code cos as the value doesn't exist currently, unable to run it with following error message:

> Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'secret.key' in value "${secret.key}"

Attempting to set it up in properties file as follows:

```
server.port=5000
#other settings
secret.data=${secret.key}
```

For example trying to use the secret value in code as follows:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Value("${secret.data}")
    private String secretData;
    .....
}
```

Please advice if there is a way around this or a better way to achieve this to stop adding sensitive data in code and git. Thanks.

Comment: I normally use AWS Secrets Manager to store my secrets that I can access at runtime.

Comment: How do you get the real secret-value for the secret-key inside springboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a system property. So the annotation you want begins `systemProperties`. Like,

```
@Value("#{systemProperties.secret.key}")
private String secretData;
```